# Sparx EA VBScript. How to "someInformationFlow.ConveyedItems.AddNew"?

Tags: enterprise-architect

**Disclaimer**: Sorry for ridiculous question. Answer must be in manual, but it's not found in docs...

I need to add an existing element to InformationFlow connector.

`dim theConnertor as EA.Connector
set theConnector = ...
...
theConnector.ConveyedItems.AddNew name, type
...`

What parameters of my element should I pass to the function `AddNew`, instead of  `name` and `type`?

Comment: I had hoped for something else as the 1000th EA question. But honestly, their help is nothing one would call brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite the help:

> To add another element to the conveyed Collection, use 'AddNew (ElementGUID,NULL)', where 'ElementGUID' is the GUID of the element to be added.

**Edit**: as per @Grigorio's comment the syntax for VB is

```
AddNew(ElementGUID, "")
```

Comment: Thnx a lot, it's works. But for VBScript it must be  'AddNew(ElementGUID, "")

Comment: I guess, their help uses Cxx syntax, though they have internally VB and JScript (or maybe it's JScript syntax). Alas, they should point out the use for their internal interpreters. Anyway, see my comment above ;-)